# If there is no gravity on the moon does the flag wave?

Tags: astronomy

We are doing a debate in astronomy and I was wondering if there is any gravity on the moon that would cause the American flag on the moon to wave at all.

Comment: There seems to be a common hidden assumption among first time students of physics that there is no gravity in outer space (e.g., from space station video footage), and outer space is a vacuum, therefore there is no gravity in a vacuum.  This is an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Gravity would not cause the flag to wave, wind would; and the flags planted on the moon are held up by a latch(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Flag_Assembly)

Also, yes, there is gravity on the Moon, about 1/6th of what it is on Earth.

Comment: Just in case the OP has been given some bad information to prompt this question, it may be worth stating plainly that flag movement seen on Apollo video is due to angular momentum imparted to the flag by the crew twisting the support rod.  In the absence of air resistance to dampen the pendulum motion, the flag oscillates longer than it would terrestrially, before becoming static.